# How to restrict spinner size in android xml

Tags: android, xml, spinner

hi i have 3 spinners in my xml.. i have coded them the same way.. but the middle spinner is bigger than the other two.. how do i make them all the same size..

[image]

all of them are right alligned... the code i used is as follows

code of erring spinner / middle spinner

```
   <Spinner
   android:id="@+id/spinyear"   
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="right"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
/>
```

the other complete code is as follows

```
<RelativeLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bgone"

tools:context="Point_Main" >

 <TableLayout
     android:layout_height="240dp"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="25sp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
     android:background="@drawable/board"
     android:weightSum="1" >
           <TableRow 
               android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
               android:layout_width="match_parent" 
               android:gravity="center"
               android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                   <TextView    
                       android:id="@+id/textquestionpaper"        
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                       android:text="@string/q"
                       android:typeface="sans"
                       android:textColor="#ffffff"
                       android:textSize="25sp"/>

           </TableRow>
           <TableRow
               android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/textscheme"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                      android:gravity="left"           
                      android:layout_weight="1.0" 
                      android:text="@string/scheme"
                      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                      android:textSize="20sp" />

                  <Spinner
                      android:id="@+id/spinscheme"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:gravity="right"           
                      android:layout_weight="1.0" 
                      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                      android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                      android:entries="@array/select_schema"/>
              </TableRow>

              <TableRow
                  android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                  android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                  >

                 <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/textyear"

                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                      android:gravity="left"
                      android:paddingRight="5dp"
                      android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                      android:text="@string/year"
                      android:typeface="sans"
                      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                      android:textSize="20sp" />

                  <Spinner
                      android:id="@+id/spinyear"   
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:gravity="right"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                      android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                   />

              </TableRow>

              <TableRow
                  android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                  android:layout_marginRight="20dp"> 


                  <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/textsubject"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                   android:gravity="left"           
                   android:layout_weight="1.0" 
                   android:text="@string/subject"
                   android:typeface="sans"
                   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                   android:textSize="20sp" />

                  <Spinner
                   android:id="@+id/spinsub"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:gravity="right"           
                   android:layout_weight="1.0" 
                   android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                   android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                   android:entries="@array/select_subject"/>

              </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>

  <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"             
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
             />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textPowered"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:text="@string/powered"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
       android:textSize="10sp"
       android:typeface="sans" />
```

***Solved***
on providing a wt tag to txt view the problem was solved....

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: post you comple xml with layout and TableLayout

Comment: @GauravPandey posted complete code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `android:layout_weight="1"` to your `textyear` :

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textyear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
             android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="year"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />
```